# Is there a Python library that would return a city when provided with zip code?

Tags: python-3.x, zipcode

So, I have zip codes in my dataframe, and I would like to construct another column in it that would contain city names according to the zip code. It would be very nice if I could extract other info, too (such as state).
For now I would need this for Germany only, but in the near future for other Europe countries, too.

I found some possible solutions, but they ether seem to be for US only ([uszipcode](https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/)), or not compatible with Python 3 ([pyzipcode](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipcode/),[pyGeoDb](https://pypi.org/project/pyGeoDb/)), and I am working with Python v3.6.

Comment: Note from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: You can use Google maps: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Comment: @glibdud I am not asking a recommendation or an opinion, nor am I starting a discussion on software libraries... I have a concrete problem, I did my research, failed couple of times, and I need help solving it... This is a very concrete question, and it is not "off-topic", just because it mentions a need for a software library.

Comment: "Is there a Python library that would..." sounds an awful lot like _"asking us to recommend or find a software library"_ to me. I'm only one vote, though. Don't sweat it.

Comment: FWIW, I agree with the OP: They're asking a boolean question - yes or no - not an opinion. It is implied that an acceptable answer would be a combination of 'Yes' and the name of the library meeting the condition. If OP had said "what is the best...", especially when there are multiple well-known options, it'd be a different story. This is more of a "I searched and can't find. Does this exist?", which I find to be a valid type of question for SO.

Comment: pyzipcode3 is compatible with python3 however it does not recognize EU zipcodes from my experience .. for example 48165 is near Detroit instead of in Westfalen

Answer (score 4):

Late to the game obviously, but if anyone arrives here via Google (like I did), check this out: https://pypi.org/project/uszipcode/

This worked for me

```
from uszipcode import SearchEngine, SimpleZipcode, Zipcode
search = SearchEngine()

def zco(x):
    city = search.by_zipcode(x).major_city
    return city if city else 'None'

df['metro'] = df['zipcode'].apply(zco)
```

Comment: I also found this via google. But somehow this doesn't return any value for zip code '96911' which belongs to Tamuning in Guam.

Comment: This lib has multiple unnecessary dependencies and i'd recommend the `zipcodes` package instead

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update**

`pyzipcode` ([link to PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipcode/)) is now compatible with Python 3. There are a few other forks of the original project floating around as well, but the linked one is the option I am using.